# How to setup signup tracking for Googles oauth2 signup cross-domain with google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I need help with getting a workaround for how to implement a valid way to track signed up visitors through the google oauth2.

The challenge is: We have tag manager container on our main domain, and a tag manager on our second main. The google analytics sources are linked into one from both.

But when we click on google sign up on our main domain it redirects to accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth... then when they signup they go to app.domain.com.
We lose tracking here.

So currently we only track "clicks" on the google sign up. How to make it so we can track the same session and get a valid signup as an event in google analytics?

Thank you!